# How can I find the source of a rain water leak above my window (and keep from getting ripped off)?

Tags: water, windows, siding, leaking

10-year-old townhome (so out of warranty, unfortunately); we've lived there two years.  In the past year, we've noticed water leaking above the living room window (the lower of the two windows in the photo).  The window faces north, and the leak seems to only be triggered by rain blown by wind from the northeast.  No problems with the upper window.

We had a contractor come out a few weeks ago to work on it.  They removed the siding panels between the two windows.  There was no obvious water staining or damage to the Tyvek or to the wood sheathing underneath.  But the drip cap (the metal rim above the blue trim) above the window was installed completely wrong.  Instead of being taped under the Tyvek, it was just sitting out in front of it, so water was getting funneled between the drip cap and the Tyvek.  The contractor installed a new drip cap and taped it...but the leak still isn't fixed.

Their proposed next step is to take off ALL the siding, all the way up to the roof, and redo all the flashing - which will apparently involve a lot of people on a lot of tall ladders and cost a lot of money.  They seem to think that the water may be getting in above the upper window.  But that seems really strange to me, because the leak is in the center of the lower window, not at the edges, so water would have to flow around the upper window and then diagonally across to the center of the lower window, all without leaving a trace of its path on the Tyvek or the sheathing.

So my questions are:

1. Is the contractor putting me on, or is their course of action reasonable?  I want to get this fixed once and for all, but I don't want to waste a bunch of their time or my money.
2. Thoughts on where the leak might be coming from?  By process of elimination, water must be traveling either behind the drip cap (behind the Tyvek, maybe even behind the sheathing?) or under it (i.e., through a crack in the blue trim at the top of the window).  I'm not sure which is more likely.
3. Is there anything I can do to try to find the source of the leak myself?  I'm too afraid of heights to get up on a ladder myself, but I have a garden hose with a power-spray extension that could probably reach the top of the lower window, if not the bottom of the upper one.  If I spray different areas trying to trigger the leak, do I need to worry about making anything worse?  Is there anything else I could try?

[image]

Comment: Water runs downhill. It could be coming in _anywhere_ above where you're seeing it, running along roof rafters, down walls, around hill, across dale, until it comes out where you're seeing it. To eliminate the possibility of a roof leak, get up in the attic and look for moisture (during or just after a rain) or water stains (if it's been dry a while).

Comment: Yes, the water could be coming in a penetration in the siding/house wrap/flashing, running until it finds a nail hole to get through the sheathing, then running down that til it hits something in the wall and runs across to where you see it inside.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  There is no attic, so unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: Odd design of cladding, what throws the water over the top of the window? The windows don't seem to have any head or sill. Architects have a lot to answer for designing stuff like this.